# apply material to face with normal pointing one way and different material to same face but with normal pointing in opposite way

Tags: materials

Is it possible to apply a material to a face and apply a different material to the same face but with the opposite normal?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one material per face, but you can set up your material to use 2 different node setups and use the "Backfacing" output of the geometry shader node as a factor for a mix node.

In this example, the backface is showing the Blue emission shader, and the front face is showing the red one.
[image: Backface]

[image]

Comment: Would there be a way to use UVs to place part of a large image in one side and a different part on the other side?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_-m7VIUNfY  Each of the walls in this model is a separate plane. I want to use a single plane for each of the the back-to-back walls.